# roslaunch terminal split screen

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am launching over a launch file several nodes in new shells as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node pkg="coral_frontend" type="CORAL_display" name="CORAL_display" output="screen" launch-prefix="gnome-terminal --geometry 80x43+55+14 -e"/>
  <node pkg="coral_frontend" type="CORAL_interface" name="CORAL_interface" output="screen" launch-prefix="gnome-terminal --geometry 56x44+788+-10 -e"/>
  <node pkg="socketcan_bridge" type="socketcan_bridge_node" name="socketcan_bridge_node" output="log"/>
  <node pkg="ipos" type="IPOS_node" name="IPOS_node" output="log"/>
</launch>
```

I wanna start the first two nodes in a terminal with splitted view, but was not able to do so with guake, byobu, yakuake or screen, since they do have just shortcuts to split the screens. Does somebody have suggestion or encountered a similar challenge?

Thank you very much!

Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301822/roslaunch-terminal-split-screen/) by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know for sure, but perhaps [fmauch/catmux](https://github.com/fmauch/catmux) can do this.

If it can't yet, it would be a good enhancement PR ([tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) appears to be able to do it).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-08-28**:
There is an answer on askubuntu where someone allegedly used tmux for this purpose. [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620742/dynamically-add-new-terminator-section-for-new-program)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-28**:
I believe that is basically what `catmux` does, but then with a bit more domain knowledge of ROS and how launchfiles work.